# Cannot Import SocketIOClientSwift

Tags: ios, socket.io

I have manually dragged the source folder to the Xcode project and then tried importing the module. Despite that I get an error when I try to add it to my app.

[image]

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: Could you post additional information for your problem? Even following the link you posed one sees it uses a different name for the module which is    `import Socket_IO_Client_Swift`

Comment: @SirKaiserKai I guess that could be the reason. I ended up using cocoapods to import it.